# Issues with 302 vanity redirect

Tags: apache, dispatcher

I have implemented the 302 vanity redirect. It is working if I access the url without .html extension and not working with .html extension. I don't see any status code and also the location header is missing in the response header. Here I am attaching the screenshots for both scenarios. Can you please advise on what could be the issue and how to fix it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjeLD.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adzVi.png)